# Log in, sign up and ask question buttons move on page load

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I played around a bit with the version of Stack Overflow to anonymous (not logged in) users, and I noticed the following behaviour (click on the image to see the full size version, some things are not easily visible in the smaller inline image):

[image]

This bug only appears when one of the Jobs ads for a specific company is visible. Because Tim Post commented that he couldn't reproduced it, I got curious and tried to load Stack Overflow via TOR with my location in the US, and there I actually don't get any of these ads that trigger the bug. I only see them when my location is Germany.

One difference seems to be that these ads inject a stylesheet called `cp.min.css`, which isn't present without them and which does apply styles to the elements that move.

Comment: I can't imagine this was intentional, unless deliberately loading UI elements misaligned and animating them back to proper alignment is the in thing now.

Comment: @BoltClock Check the full size version, the vibrating "Sign Up" Button has to be intentional.

Comment: "they trigger consistently in different browsers" - Not the case for me. No wiggling (though there is a slight movement involving the side bars). The icons don't wiggle. Tested on latest chrome in incognito.

Comment: same here.. no repro in chrome  in mac

Comment: @Rob I got it on Chrome and Firefox under Windows, I tried it now on Firefox on Linux and don't get it there. They might be A/B testing this, or this might be unintentional.

Comment: I now also saw a version with the three moving elements, but not the "Sign Up" button wiggle. This looks to me like they're A/B testing multiple variants.

Comment: @MadScientist I think you're right, as I can see some movement of the first two buttons, but the layout it's different, with Sign Up expanded. Chrome on Mac

Comment: It happens to me, but only when the ["we have X open jobs"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfhgB.png) CTA is showing.

Comment: What is "the anonymous version of Stack Overflow"?

Comment: @LangeHaare I clarified it in the post, it's the version that users that are not logged in receive.

Comment: @MadScientist: "*Check the full size version, the vibrating "Sign Up" Button has to be intentional.*" This all looks like a layout bug, even the vibrating button. That's caused by the layout shifting in pixels. There's an imaginary line that separates the right panel from the main one, and the top-bar layout is partially based on that. When that line shifts to the right, it causes all of these visual glitches, since everything is based on it. The fact that it only happens as the page is loading also suggests that it's not intentional, since different people have different page load speeds.

Comment: +1 for retagging this as [tag:bug]. Easy mistake to make with transitions and no reason for it to be intentional.

Comment: @NicolBolas it's probably a bug, but when I looked at it early this morning, it seemed to be too many different behaviours to be the result of a single bug. And with all the stuff SE has been experimenting on SO, it seemed possible that this is a terribly misguided attempt to increase user engagement or something like this.

Comment: OCD folks be like IAintGotNoCompulsiveProblem.gif

Comment: Can we get your browser details? I can't reproduce this on Chrome, Safari or FF on a Mac (all latest stable versions). Tried full screen, resized, etc .. same thing, can't reproduce. I'm hoping this wasn't as accidentally fixed as it was introduced because I really want to see those dancing buttons.

Comment: @TimPost I've reproduced it on Linux and Windows, both Chrome and Firefox. I doesn't happen always, and to me it looks like DavidG was right in the comments above and it is triggered by a specific type of job ad.

Comment: @TimPost I just tried it again, and I noticed that in the cases where it happens, the buttons do have additional styles applied that originate from `cp.min.css`, but those styles aren't there in the cases where the movement doesn't happen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was a classic CSS naming collision issue: our Company Page ads were using class names that the hosting page also had defined, but with slightly different stylings. Both classes had defined `transition` properties, hence the animation when ads loaded.

Normally we prefix all CSS classes for our Job / Company Page Ads, these particular ones happened to fall through the cracks, so to speak. They should be fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

To be absolutely clear. This is a bug. It is not intentional. We will investigate and once we have a repro we will fix it.