# Please provide a tagline with site purpose

Tags: discussion, new-users, user-interface

Would it be possible to add a tagline or subtitle for Stack Overflow in an attempt to educate users of the purpose of the site? Maybe something like:

[image]

Or:

[image]

What I am finding is, some users still don't realize Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. Here's a recent comment about it. (A link to the question is withheld to avoid the Meta effect so the fellow does not get bombed into the stone age).

[image]

However, I don't believe its completely a user's fault. I feel the Stack Exchange network does a rather poor job at educating users. I think most users know what to expect at [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but I can't say the same of Stack Overflow because "stack overflow" is sort of ambiguous and has historically accepted a wide array of questions (and the off-topic ones feed the problem).

I also realize the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) are pretty clear. But I feel if RTFM was going to work, then it probably would have happened in the last 50 years or so. I'm not even sure making the Tour compulsory would help with the issue.

Finally, I don't recall what the "new user signup" work flow looks like. There may be another opportunity to educate users when they signup, especially if clear and conspicuous notice is not given.

Comment: [Just saying.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Cq3.png)

Comment: @animuson - Good point (do you want to add it to this post?). Apparently, its still not enough. I seem to recall from a UX class that the site should tell users at least three times. I took the class years ago in college, and a lot of the finer UX points are now lost (for me). But the 3x still stand out in my mind.

Comment: @animuson - Do you think the site could make the text "throb" by cycling from lighter to darker? That should be harder to avoid as the throbbing will draw the eye to the text.

Comment: That said, the [page users land on the first time they ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) doesn't explicitly mention the topic anywhere on the page (only links to the on-topic page), but does mention looking up other topics on Stack Exchange. That's... kind of weird.

Comment: I like what this post diagnoses, not so much the remedy

Comment: anonymous visitors are already educated about the purpose of the site with a [gigantic bright banner that covers half screen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357858/839601), aren't they?

Comment: Thanks @gnat. Why is the message not getting through, and what can be done to solve the problem?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that'd do any good.

The UI already makes it *abundantly* clear what you're supposed to do, like @animuson pointed out in the comments.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Cq3.png]

(image courtesy of animuson)

If people won't read what it says *right in the textbox that they're typing their question into*, what makes you think they'd pay more attention to a tagline?

Comment: Well, the UX has not me the rule of three. In UX design, you must tell someone something three times. My hopes are eventually the prominent one as te subtitle gets through. Since Animuson's comment, I like the idea of non-static text - make it throb; make it blink; make it do something to draw attention to it.

Comment: @jww Question templates will be coming so they should serve as another reminder that you need to ask a programming question

Comment: Blinking is so last-century. Maybe they could make the text [wiggle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357875/log-in-sign-up-and-ask-question-buttons-move-on-page-load).

Comment: Also, I don't find any references for "rule of three" in the domain of UX. I'm quite familiar with the term as applied to C++ class design (and also the rule of five, and the rule of zero). The only thing I can find relevant in UX is [this article dispelling a different rule of three as a myth](http://uxmyths.com/post/654026581/myth-all-pages-should-be-accessible-in-3-clicks). It does seem to strain the imagination that people who ignore two warnings would magically heed a third. The fundamental problem is that people don't care. They just want an answer, and they'll type into any textbox.